# Python KeyError when iterating dict from JSON-file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, keyerror

I'm trying to read a JSON file (and eventually save the contents to a database), but I'm getting an KeyError when running the code below. [See sample JSON](http://pastebin.com/JSj0rLrY) for reference.

The keys `'durationTimeFrom'` and `'durationTimeTo'` does not exist in all cases in the JSON file (only when `eventType` is `80`, I think).

How do I properly identify missing keys before attempting to read the value, and/or how do I insert dummy-keys for the items that do not have the key already?

I have already searched Google/StackOverflow and tried `if key in dict:` and `dict.get(key)` without success.

```
import json

source = "feed_traffic.json" # JSON file to process
data = json.loads(open(source).read()) # Process JSON

total = data["events"]["totalCount"]
index = 0

events = data["events"]["list"][index:total]

for event in events:

    eid = event["id"]
    type = event['eventType']
    header = event['headingText']
    lat = event['latitude']
    long = event['longitude']
    created = event['created']
    updated = event['updated']
    expires = event['expireTime']
    validFrom = event['durationTimeFrom']
    validTo = event['durationTimeTo']
    status = event['status']

    # Just to check all is well, out data in console
    print("Traffic Event", index, ":", eid, "-", type, "-", header, "(", long, ",", lat, ")")

    index = index+1
```

Comment: have you tried implementing error and exception handling? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: event.get('id') returns None if the key doesn't exist

Comment: `help(dict.get)` says `D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.` You can provide your own default. Supposing you want the default id to be -1, you would `eid = event.get("id", -1)`.

Comment: @glls Yeah, that is my next step ;-) Thx for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.get`. it works fine for me. You should change as follows.

```
# before
validFrom = event['durationTimeFrom']
validTo = event['durationTimeTo']

# after
validFrom = event.get('durationTimeFrom')
validTo = event.get('durationTimeTo')
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what I did wrong the first time, but I was getting the same error. This sorted it out.